How to prove injectivity? An infinite set $E$ is bijective to $\mathbb{N}$ (Royden "Real Analysis Third Edition")
On p.21 in "Real Analysis Third Edition" by H. L. Royden.

if an infinite set $E$ is the range of a sequence $\langle x_n\rangle$, then $E$ can be put in one-to-one correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$. To do this we define a function $\varphi$ from $\mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{N}$ by recursion as follows: Let $\varphi(1)=1$, and define $\varphi(n+1)$ to be the smallest value of $m$ such that $x_m\neq x_i$ for all $i\leq \varphi(n)$. Since $E$ is infinite, such an $m$ always exists, and by the well-ordering principle for $\mathbb{N}$ there is always a least such $m$. The correspondence $n\mapsto x_{\varphi(n)}$ is a one-to-one correspondence between $\mathbb{N}$ and $E$.

I tried to prove this fact as follows.

By the definition of $\varphi$, $\varphi(n)<\varphi(n+1)$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
I want to prove the correspondence $n\mapsto x_{\varphi(n)}$ is injective.
The following is a proof of surjectivity.
Let $x_{i_1}\in E$.
Then, there is $n_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\varphi(n_1)\leq i_1<\varphi(n_1+1)$.
Since $i_1<\varphi(n_1+1)$, $x_{i_1}=x_{i_2}$ for some $i_2\leq\varphi(n_1)$.
If $\varphi(n_1)=i_2$, then $n_1\mapsto x_{\varphi(n_1)}=x_{i_2}=x_{i_1}$.
Suppose that $\varphi(n_1)>i_2$.
There is $n_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\varphi(n_2)\leq i_2<\varphi(n_2+1)$ and $n_2<n_1$.
Since $i_2<\varphi(n_2+1)$, $x_{i_2}=x_{i_3}$ for some $i_3\leq\varphi(n_2)$.
If $\varphi(n_2)=i_3$, then $n_2\mapsto x_{\varphi(n_2)}=x_{i_3}=x_{i_2}=x_{i_1}$.
Suppose that $\varphi(n_2)>i_3$.
There is $n_3\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\varphi(n_3)\leq i_3<\varphi(n_3+1)$ and $n_3<n_2$.
$\dots$
There is no sequence $\langle n_i\rangle$ such that $n_i\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n_1>n_2>n_3>\cdots$.
So, the correspondence $n\mapsto x_{\varphi(n)}$ is surjective.

How to prove injectivity?

Since $x_{\varphi(n+1)}\neq x_i$ for all $i\leq\varphi(n)$, $x_{\varphi(n+1)}\neq x_{\varphi(i)}$ for $i\leq n$ because $\varphi(i)\leq\varphi(n)$ if $i\leq n$.
So, the correspondence $n\mapsto x_{\varphi(n)}$ is injective.
Is this ok?
